# Using java to read files having oracle BFILE datatype from database

Tags: java, oracle10g

I have a table which contains location to files on the external filesystem.
The datatype used for column containing file locations is BFILE.

How to read such files from the database using java?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please read following post and [this Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/oralob3.htm#1059336) will be helpful

This sample demonstrates Oracle JDBC BFILE support. It illustrates filling a table with BFILEs and includes a utility for dumping the contents of a BFILE. For information on BFILEs.

```
/* 
 * This sample demonstrate basic File support
 */

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

//including this import makes the code easier to read

import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;

// needed for new BFILE class

import oracle.sql.*;

public class FileExample{

public static void main (String args [])throws Exception{
// Register the Oracle JDBC driver
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

// Connect to the database
// You can put a database name after the @ sign in the connection URL.
//
// The sample creates a DIRECTORY and you have to be connected as
// "system" to be able to run the test.
// I you can't connect as "system" have your system manager
// create the directory for you, grant you the rights to it, and
// remove the portion of this program that drops and creates the directory.
Connection conn =
  DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@", "system", "manager");

// It's faster when auto commit is off
conn.setAutoCommit (false);

// Create a Statement
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ();

try
{
  stmt.execute ("drop directory TEST_DIR");
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
  // An error is raised if the directory does not exist.  Just ignore it.
}
stmt.execute ("create directory TEST_DIR as '/tmp/filetest'");

try
{
  stmt.execute ("drop table test_dir_table");
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
  // An error is raised if the table does not exist.  Just ignore it.
}

// Create and populate a table with files
// The files file1 and file2 must exist in the directory TEST_DIR created
// above as symbolic name for /private/local/filetest.
stmt.execute ("create table test_dir_table (x varchar2 (30), b bfile)");
stmt.execute ("insert into test_dir_table values 
               ('one', bfilename ('TEST_DIR', 'file1'))");
stmt.execute ("insert into test_dir_table values 
               ('two', bfilename ('TEST_DIR', 'file2'))");

// Select the file from the table
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery ("select * from test_dir_table");
while (rset.next ())
{
  String x = rset.getString (1);
  BFILE bfile = ((OracleResultSet)rset).getBFILE (2);
  System.out.println (x + " " + bfile);

  // Dump the file contents
  dumpBfile (conn, bfile);
}

// Close all resources
rset.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();}

// Utility function to dump the contents of a Bfile

static void dumpBfile (Connection conn, BFILE bfile) throws Exception{

System.out.println ("Dumping file " + bfile.getName());

System.out.println ("File exists: " + bfile.fileExists());

System.out.println ("File open: " + bfile.isFileOpen());

System.out.println ("Opening File: ");

bfile.openFile();

System.out.println ("File open: " + bfile.isFileOpen());

long length = bfile.length();
System.out.println ("File length: " + length);

int chunk = 10;

InputStream instream = bfile.getBinaryStream();

// Create temporary buffer for read
byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk];

// Fetch data  
while ((length = instream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
  System.out.print("Read " + length + " bytes: ");

  for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    System.out.print(buffer[i]+" ");
  System.out.println();
}

// Close input stream
instream.close();

// close file handler
bfile.closeFile();}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/oralob3.htm#1059336

There you will find many examples like this

```
OraclePreparedStatement ops = (OraclePreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement
                        ("INSERT INTO my_bfile_table VALUES (?,?)");
ops.setString(1,"one");
ops.setBFILE(2, bfile);
ops.execute();
```